# A single UTF8 accented character causing issues with preg_replace()

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-replace

When running `à` through `preg_replace` I get a �

```
$text = "dedicado à gramática";
preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $text);
```

OUTPUT: dedicado � gramática

What is happening and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: A [`u`nicode](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) flag wouldn't hurt the regex ;)

Comment: @Rizier123 of course... ugh. thanks!

Comment: Or start your pattern with `(*UTF8)` and eventually `(*UCP)`